# Are there any consequences to "Draw over other apps" and are there any complications regarding using it

Tags: android, service, floating

I know that you can create floating ChatHeads as I've seen the tutorials and all, but I never hear of any consequences to using/abusing this feature. I know it's meant for system critical messages, but also that it CAN be used to allow floating applications.

What I mean by "consequences and complications" is the following...

1) If you draw on top of another app, is the app being drawn over still considered in the foreground, even if the user is interacting with the floating app? Would this be preferable to having a transparent "floating" activity? I'm mainly interested because I want to ensure that the other app isn't killed due to the overlay itself.

2) If the floating app/view is inefficient/buggy, could that impact the performance of the app being drawn over?

3) Can you add fragments to the view being drawn over? If so, when the background app is hidden (I.E Home button), what happens to the life-cycle of that view? Does it die when the app being drawn over dies?

4) I'm assuming there is an easy way to remove the floating view once added?

Comment: This capability is a security issue, as malware can use it to attempt to cover up critical bits of the UI to confuse the user (e.g., retitle system warnings). That's why on Android 6.0 and higher, the user has to go through separate steps to agree to allow your app to draw over other apps, beyond you asking for the permission in the manifest. It will also fail outright on certain devices (e.g., Jide's Remix series).

Comment: I see, so I most definitely should not rely on the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission for future version of Android. Why does it fail "outright" on "Jide's Remix series", whatever that is, even if it has permissions?

Comment: I don't know the exact symptoms. I know that Jide has been advising people that these sorts of popups don't work on devices running their version of Android. I presume that it interferes with how they implement multi-window support for Android.